# Making responsive grid with CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make a responsive home page. However, I couldn't achieve what I want. I will explain better with some codes and image.

Currently my home page looks like this,

[image]

First of all I would like to have the two bottom buttons align with the image keeping in mind that the top 3 buttons align with the image's top.

I tried to add margins and padding, but it breaks the page in responsive design. I would like the page intact(resposive) upto atleast 1024p. I could manage something else below 1024 (may be change of template to suite from 480p to 1023p).

```css
.HomeContent {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #c4c4c4;
  margin: 1% 5%;
}

.HomeContent #LeftImageBox {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.HomeContent #LeftImageBox img {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.HomeContent #RightContentBox {
  float: left;
  width: 54%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.HomeContent #TopMenuBox,#WelcomeBox,#SubRightBox1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: 0 1px 1px 0;
}

.HomeContent .tile-grid {
  text-align: justify;
}

.HomeContent .tile-grid li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

.HomeContent .tile-grid: after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%; /* Ensures there are at least 2 lines of text, so justification works */
  display: inline-block;
}

.HomeContent .tile-grid span {
  background-color: #f26323;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.HomeContent .tile-grid span: hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #f26323;
}
```

```html
<div class="HomeContent">
  <div id="LeftImageBox">
    <img alt="" src="http://dummyimage.com/498x500/4f4f4f/ffffff.png" />
  </div>

  <div id="RightContentBox">

    <div id="TopMenuBox">
      <ul class="tile-grid">
        <li><a><span>bathroom</span></a></li>
        <li><a><span>kitchen</span></a></li>
        <li><a><span>laundry</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="WelcomeBox">
      <h1><span>This is ASOS</span></h1>
      <h3><span>YOUR ONE-STOP<br />FASHION DESTINATION</span></h3>
      <p>Shop from over 850 of the best brands, including ASOS' own label.Plus, get your daily fix of the freshest style, celebrity and music news.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="SubRightBox1">
      <ul class="tile-grid">
        <li><a><span>new products</span></a></li>
        <li><a><span>tips &amp; trends</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you want those 3 buttons (bathroom, kitchen, laundry) to be placed on top of the 498x500 image and those 2 buttons (new products, tips & trends) on the bottom whenever the browser size shrinks?

Comment: uh...you aren't using media queries. How do you expect this to be responsive? [See this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: theoretically, you could do a responsive site without media queries, so @sgarcia you are not totally right.

Comment: @JTrixx16, no I would like the image to sit on right and other contents on left. I want the bottom 2 buttons to come further down so it aligns with image size ("parallel to each other" a better word?) . I have a screen with 2500 in width. so when  I resize the screen from 2500 to 1024 iwant both left and right shrinks together and also aligns fine as two square boxes.  The way you have described is what i have in my mind for anything less than 1024.

Comment: @sgarcia I will be using media quries for anything less than 1024p. My problem is now with the screen size above 1024p. i couldn't get the button at the bottom to align with the image bottom (parallel). When I style the alignment for 1024 bit the right box goes upwards for the screen size above 1024. I can again do numerous media queries for different screen size here. But I am doing something right and feel like there may be a better way of doing it!. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: Whoever downvoted must be more intelligent than me and find my question silly or sloppy. Wonder why the person didn't post his answer or at least criticise me, so I can improve. Easy to judge I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a workaround by adding `::after` class to the `<p>` tag and increased the line-height. It pushed the buttons further below. It works for anything above 1024p. I will have another media query for 1024P and make a mobile version of anything below that level.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@media` to make changes whenever the browser size shrinks.

For example:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    // Here is an example:
    // When the browser size shrinks down to 1024px or less,
    // The background-color of the body will change to red.
    body {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

When you resize your browser larger than 1024px, the red background color will be removed.